Calculate the solubility product of calomel (Hg2Cl2) using potential?
How do you calculate the solubility product of calomel if the potential of the calomel electrode (Hg2Cl2 / Hg / KCl) is given against a standard hydrogen cell with E = 3.22 V. A 1M KCl solution was used and the chloride ions have an activity of 0.6. I set up the Nernst equation so that the potential only depends on the chloride ions. If the solubility product is rearranged according to the chloride ions and inserted into the Nernst equation, a strange result comes out.
My solution:

